# Regarding YUI3 for begineers

Tags: spring-mvc, web, yui3, web-development-server

May be this question is not appropriate for this forum , but i tried a lot on google but didnt found any good book for YUI3 for begineers except cookbook.
I need help, thats why i am posting.
I am looking for a good book or tutorial (except YUI3 library) that explains complete website development using YUI for front end and spring framework for server coding. It it includes a complete project like building any forum or e-commerce site , it will be very helpful for me.

Thanks, and apologies if i posted asked something wrong on this forum,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever did some web project using jquery, I recommand [the javascript Rosetta stone](http://www.jsrosettastone.com) for documentation

The tutorials in YUI3 library are also a good way to learn the basics

However, it was announced that active development by Yahoo! would end. So it's up to you if you want to start with a framework that could be no longer maintained

Comment: Hi , Thanks for replying. I want to know that can i make rest calls from YUI and server code in Spring. Is this is a good combination for any web project?

Answer (score 1):

For YUI3 there are some nice videos on youtube. Actually playlists by the YUI3 team members. They are good in understanding the architecture of YUI framework. Also if you google you can find a good book online named 'YUI3 cookbook'. That is also a good read. I am also new to JS and YUI3. I am also going to read JS book 'Javascript the good parts'.